# How to Access a Field or attribute from a many to many table using Linq?

Tags: c#, linq

Linq - I am trying to get list of items in which every item is assigned to a specific supplier and this supplier can have more than 1 Item type he can supply so a many to many table was created including a supplierId  and  supplierItemTypeId

The point is that I need to get List of items for each supplierItemType

[view in the visual studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i1wI8.png)

```
   var TotalAssignedItems =  _context.SupplierAssignedOrderItems.Include(x=>x.Item)
        .Include(x=>x.Supplier)
        .ThenInclude(x=>x.TypeSuppliers).ToList();
    
      var FirstTypeItems = TotalAssignedItems.Where(x => 
         x.Supplier.TypeSuppliers.supplierItemTypdId == 1).ToList();
```

The above  code  is what I wanted to do but I am not able to access
the attributes of the many to many table(TypeSuppliers)

Comment: What is the type of Supplier & TypeSuppliers? `List` ?

Comment: Supplier is a table with the supplier  info and Type supplier is the many to many table has the supplierId with the supplierItemTypeId  List  is a datatype in C# which is just like  a collection of Models

Answer (score 1):

> `x.Supplier.TypeSuppliers.supplierItemTypdId == 1`

`TypeSuppliers` is a collection. It doesn't have a single `supplierItemTypdId` property. It has many TypeSupplier objects, each of which has a `supplierItemTypdId` property

---

Let's make the problem simpler to think about:

```
class Person{
  string Name;
}

var people = new []{
  new Person { Name = "John" },
  new Person { Name = "Jane" }
};
```

We want to know "in our list of people, does any person have a name of John?"  Note, we do not want "people where the name is John", we want to know "is one of them called John or not?"

We would not do this:

```
people.Name == "John"
```

We should do this:

```
people.Any(person => person.Name == "John" )
```

---

Going back to the original problem.. We want to know "our assigned item Supplier has a list of TypeSuppliers; does any one typeSupplier in the list have a supplierItemTypdId that is equal to 1?"

```
x.Supplier.TypeSuppliers.Any(ts => ts.supplierItemTypdId == 1)
```

---

May I recommend you stop using `x‘ for everything and start using variable names that reflect the type of object you're dealing with- it will help keep things straight in your mind as to what is what at various levels of nesting in your query..

```
TotalAssignedItems.Where(ai => 
  ai.Supplier.TypeSuppliers.Any(
    ts => ts.supplierItemTypdId == 1
  )
).ToList();
```

Also, please follow c# naming conventions - local variables are camelCase (you should call it **t**otalAssignedItems) and properties are PascalCase (you should call it **S**upplierItemTypdId)

ps; supplierItemTypdId seems to have a typo

Comment: Thank you for your valuable repliy i will make sure to follow such instructions

Answer (score 0):

Use join

```
var Result = (from s in _context.Suppliers
             join t in _context.TypeSuppliers on s.typeId equals t.supplierItemTypdId
             where t.supplierItemTypdId == 1
             select s
             ).ToList();
```

Comment: Supplier is a normal table the one i can't access is the TypeSuppliers

Comment: Can you post the class Structure of TypeSuppliers and Suppliers in the main question

Comment: Updated the answer, check it out

Comment: i will post them just a few mins